# Scripts and Styles are not enqueuing in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am converting a html template in wordpress theme, I tried to enqueue the styles and scripts in functions.php but some are working and some are not working my custom css is also not working only bootstrap classes are working
Below is my header.php code:

```
<?php
 /**
 * Header file for the Twenty Twenty WordPress default theme.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twenty
 * @since Twenty Twenty 1.0
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* 
these tags -->s
<title> Unistore Pro &middot; Premium Responsive E-Commerce Template</title>

<meta name="description" content="Bootstrap template for you store - E-Commerce Bootstrap Template">
<meta name="keywords" content="unistore, e-commerce bootstrap template, premium e-commerce bootstrap 
template, premium bootstrap template, bootstrap template, e-commerce, bootstrap template, sunrise 
digital">
<meta name="author" content="Sunrise Digital">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/ionicons-2.0.1/css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:400,100,300' rel='stylesheet' 
type='text/css'>

<link href="assets/css/custom-scroll/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

**Now here is the code of functions.php enqueue code:**

```
    function Twenty_twenty_files() { 
    wp_enqueue_style('twentytwenty_style', get_stylesheet_uri()); 
    } 

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Twenty_twenty_files');


    function Twenty_twenty_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_script('twentytwenty_script', get_theme_file_uri(), array(), '1.0'); 

    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/custom- 
   scroll/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-touch-navigation', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/bootstrap.js' ), 
    array(), '20181231', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/bootstrap.min.js' ), 
    array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/carousel.js' ), 
    array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/carousel-product.js' ), 
    array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/checkout.js' ), 
    array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/color-calculations.js' 
    ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/core.js' ), array(), 
    '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize.js' ), 
    array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize-controls.js' 
    ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize-preview.js' 
    ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/editor-script-block.js' 
    ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/index.js' ), array(), 
     '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( 
    '/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/jquery.ui.touch- 
   punch.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/jquery-latest.min.js' 
    ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js' ), 
    array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js' ), 
    array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/npm.js' ), array(), 
    '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js' 
    ), array(), '20181214', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/store.js' ), array(), 
    '20181214', true );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Twenty_twenty_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you give unique handle to all `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style`. the first parameter is the handle. you can also remove js based on the handle using `wp_dequeue_script`. try below code.

```
function Twenty_twenty_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty_script',        get_theme_file_uri(), array(), '1.0'); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentytwenty-priority-menu', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/custom- scroll/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap',                  get_theme_file_uri( '/js/bootstrap.js' ), array(), '20181231', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-min',              get_theme_file_uri( '/js/bootstrap.min.js' ),  array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'carousel',                   get_theme_file_uri( '/js/carousel.js' ),  array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'carousel-product',           get_theme_file_uri( '/js/carousel-product.js' ),  array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'checkout',                   get_theme_file_uri( '/js/checkout.js' ),  array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'color-calculations',         get_theme_file_uri( '/js/color-calculations.js'  ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'core',                       get_theme_file_uri( '/js/core.js' ), array(),  '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customize',                  get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize.js' ),  array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customize-controls',         get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize-controls.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customize-preview',          get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize-preview.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'editor-script-block',        get_theme_file_uri( '/js/editor-script-block.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'index',                      get_theme_file_uri( '/js/index.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'touchSwipe',                 get_theme_file_uri( '/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'touch- punch',               get_theme_file_uri( '/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-latest',              get_theme_file_uri( '/js/jquery-latest.min.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui',                  get_theme_file_uri( '/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry',                    get_theme_file_uri( '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'npm',                        get_theme_file_uri( '/js/npm.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'skip-link-focus-fix',        get_theme_file_uri( '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'store',                      get_theme_file_uri( '/js/store.js' ), array(), '20181214', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Twenty_twenty_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add style and script like below code, And you need add unique for all style and script for id please check attached image where you can change id.

wp_enqueue_style('slick', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/slick.css';
wp_enqueue_script('general', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/general.js';[image]

Comment: Thank you i was missing this point now scripts and styles are loaded as i checked by inspecting the page